# hadoop:Not able to run a mapreduce job

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, distributed-computing

I have made 3 files in java,made a jar file and wrote this line to execute the MapReduce code:

```
hadoop jar /home/xyz/Documents/hadoop-2.7.3/abc1.jar woq.WordCount /test/vocab.txt /test/output3
```

The jar filename is **abc1.jar**,**woq** is the package name and **WordCount** is the main class in which the job is defined for mapreduce code.When this line is executed,following error is displayed:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: woq.WordCount
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:214)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
```

Any suggestions on what I point am I missing in executing the above line?

Output of the grep command(in comments):

```
   Sun Jan 22 21:04:20 IST 2017 WordCountMapper.class
   Sun Jan 22 21:04:20 IST 2017 WordCountReducer.class
   Sun Jan 22 21:04:20 IST 2017 WordCount.class
```

Comment: list the classes in your jar with `jar -tvf abc1.jar`, it should give you the package hierarchy of the WordCount class.

Comment: It gives 5 classes.3 of them are the one which I compiled and 2 additional files

Comment: Can you grep the output for `WordCount`?

Comment: how can I see it's output if this command is not running?

Comment: I meant, `jar -tvf abc1.jar | grep -i 'WordCount'`

Comment: Yeah,it shows all the 3 classes.

Comment: Please update its output in your post

Comment: please see the post now,I have updated it.

Comment: I don see any `woq` here.

Comment: but I have written package woq in the starting of every file,can you please tell what point I missed?

Comment: Try submitting the job without `woq`, the class name would be only `WordCount`. It should work.

Comment: It gives an error mentioning:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: WordCount (wrong name: woq/WordCount)

Comment: Do you have a line like `package woq` in all your classes? But such hierarchy does not exist in the jar structure. You can remove that line and recompile it.

Comment: yes in all the files.just trying without the package line

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133818/discussion-between-ssharma-and-franklinsijo).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments,

The class files appear to have the line `package woq;` in them without the acutal directory structure. You can either create a parent directory `woq` or remove that line from the files and recompile it.

If you remove the line, you can submit the job like this

```
hadoop jar /home/xyz/Documents/hadoop-2.7.3/abc1.jar WordCount /test/vocab.txt /test/output3
```